# Fill in the blank: Red text with dotted lines

Tags: macros

I am trying to achieve what is already in [Fill in the blank: text wrapping & math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147177/169271) but with dotted lines. The line should have the length of a `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` and it should allow line break. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ulem,xcolor}

\newcommand\ulemfill{\bgroup\color{red}\markoverwith{\textcolor{black}{\rule[-.6ex]{2pt}{.5pt}}}\ULon}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item My name is \ulemfill{Nadia \hfill}
\item My hobby is \ulemfill{\lipsum[1] \hfill}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/5764)

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqO4.png)?

Comment: Hi @Werner! I've just edited my codes. The dots should span the lines regardless of the number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the solution suggested in [Fill in the blank: text wrapping & math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147177/5764) by adding a blank underline:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ulemfill}[1]{\ulemfill@{#1\hfill\mbox{}}}
\newcommand{\ulemfill@}{\bgroup\color{red}\markoverwith % change red to white to hide text
  {\textcolor{black}{\rule[-.6ex]{.3ex}{.5pt}\rule[-.6ex]{.3ex}{0pt}}}\ULon}% underline color for ulem
                    % ^ Solid rule             ^ Blank rule

\begin{document}

\ulemfill{%
  Nadia%
}

\ulemfill{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a venenatis lacus. Nunc vitae 
  mollis neque. Maecenas vel arcu erat. In bibendum cursus interdum. Orci varius natoque penatibus 
  et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla aliquet arcu eget velit mollis 
  ultricies. Phasellus arcu sem, bibendum ut lorem non, interdum dictum mi. Nulla vitae libero 
  congue, ullamcorper odio ac, ultrices magna. Suspendisse bibendum tortor eu risus laoreet, ac 
  consequat arcu commodo. Nullam sagittis nibh semper dui tempus accumsan. Vivamus tempor dapibus 
  ante sit amet vulputate.%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works in an enumerate environment too.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{ulem,xcolor, linegoal}

\newcommand\udotfill[1]{\hspace{-0.65em} \rlap{\raisebox{-0.6ex}{\makebox[\linegoal]{\dotfill}}} \color{red}#1}

\begin{document}

My name is \udotfill{Aiman}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code does not work when I put it in an enumerate environment. Everything is written in red and the dots do not span the line.

Comment: @Nadia: For the color problem, replace `\color{red}#1` with `\textcolor{red}{#1}`. For the dots span in lists, I'll try to find a solution.