# How to turn on and off some parts of a TeX file?

Tags: comments

I would simply like to have the possibility to turn on and off some parts of a TeX file. For example, when writing a course assignment, it should be possible to hide the solutions to my students, but to show them to me after a new compilation. Hint: The `comment` package does not work for me, since it does not understand German Umlaute like, e.g., Ä, Ö, Ü, etc. In general, this package seems to be a little bit out of date...

Comment: It would be nice if you posted a minimal compilable example we can work with (e.g., including those Ä, Ö, etc. that don't work for you).

Comment: You can use the `comment` package with utf-8 characters, by adopting the trick described by egreg in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159824/27635

Comment: Or you can use the comment environment of verbatim package

Comment: Depending on how you want to implement it, this question could be very much related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125840/create-fill-in-the-blank-version-of-a-document-with-ability-to-toggle-blanks-on

Comment: Check out the `exam` class and its `\printanswers`/`\noprintanswers` commands. I believe the `exsheets` package can also do this, though I'm less familiar.

Comment: Weird, but I am not able to post a minimal example, because wrapping seems to be impossible here... I am very sorry for that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I use the [`ocgx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) package, or I use basic two-way cross-referencing to switch between different parts of a document.